How to set the permissions of all files in a folder, given directory name using python?
Self explanatory. But basically I'm trying to shutil.rmtree ~/.ssh and a private key has restrictive read/write permissions.
I don't want to make any assumptions about the name of the key, so I want to chmod 777 everything in ~/.ssh and then shutil.rmtree it. How do I do that?

sudo chmod -R 777 ~/.ssh

This should do the trick
Edit: Sorry I didn't read the python in title. I think you can use this in nested for loop.
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(ssh_dir):
    for d in dirs:
        os.chmod(os.path.join(root, d), 0o777)
    for f in files:
        os.chmod(os.path.join(root, f), 0o777)


did you read the question? answer needs to be in python, and I don't want to use subprocess package.

hmm, nevermind the pythonic solution is ugly and it's easier to just do subprocess.run(["sudo", "chmod", "-R", "777", expanduser("~/.ssh")])
